# Property to check whether a row in grid view has been modified

Tags: asp.net

Is there a simple property or method to check whether a row changed or column value has been changed in my grid view. I also want to get the index of modified/changed row

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView Name="gridview1" OnRowUpdating="GridViewUpdateEventHandler" />
```

If I remember correctly there is an abundance of tutorials for gridviews and how to manipulate data.

Comment: I am using windows application.Can you give an example code suitable for my requirement

Comment: @KD then why you tagged it as asp.net

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no simple property for that. But...

Here is a method for that on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

You'll have to modify it for your data and your control names to verify, but it's all there, straight from the keyboard of Microsoft.

```
protected bool IsRowModified(GridViewRow r)
{
    int currentID;
    string currentLastName;
    string currentFirstName;

    currentID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[r.RowIndex].Value);

    currentLastName = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("LastNameTextBox")).Text;
    currentFirstName = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("FirstNameTextBox")).Text;

    System.Data.DataRow row =
        originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("EmployeeID = {0}", currentID))[0];

    if (!currentLastName.Equals(row["LastName"].ToString())) { return true; }
    if (!currentFirstName.Equals(row["FirstName"].ToString())) { return true; }

    return false;
}
```